# Bootstrap Scrollspy data-offset not working?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I have a page where I use scrollspy to navigate to sections of the page. It all works perfect with one exception:
I use a .sticky-top on my navigation and this now covers part of the section I scroll to.
From the documentation I understand I should use data-offset to prevent this from happening.
Unfortunately it's not working.
I've tried both data-offset as well as data-bs-offset, neither works.
I'm sure I'm missing something here but what?

Here is my code:

```
    <body data-bs-spy="scroll" data-bs-target="#nav" data-bs-offset="500" data-bs-smooth-scroll="true">
    
    
    
        <div class='sticky-top top'>
            <div class='container'>
              <div class='row justify-content-center'>
                  <div class='col-sm-2'></div>
                  <div class='col-sm-8 island-logo '> <a href="{% url 'rhumSite:home' %}"><img id='brand-logo' src="{% static 'logos/logo-1.png' %}" alt="Logo"></a></div>
                  <div class='col-sm-2 socials'>
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><img class='img-fluid' src="{% static 'logos/social_icons-01.png' %}" alt="Facebook logo"></a>
                        <a href="https://twitter.com/?lang=en"><img class='img-fluid' src="{% static 'logos/social_icons-02.png' %}" alt="Twitter logo"></a>
                        <a href="https://www.instagram.com//?hl=en"><img class='img-fluid' src="{% static 'logos/social_icons-03.png' %}" alt="Instagram logo"></i></a>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
    
    
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light container" id='nav'>
              <button class="navbar-toggler mx-auto mb-3" 
                      type="button" 
                      data-bs-toggle="collapse" 
                      data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" 
                      aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" 
                      aria-expanded="false" 
                      aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-bars hamburger"></i>
                  </span>
                </button>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
                <div class="navbar-nav">
                  <a class="nav-link top-link " href="#ourstory" title='OUR STORY'>OUR STORY</a>
                  <a class="nav-link top-link " href="#process" title='PROCESS'>PROCESS</a>
                  <a class="nav-link top-link " href="#rhums" title='RHUMS'>RHUMS</a>
                  <a class="nav-link top-link " href="#cocktails" title='COCKTAILS'>COCKTAILS</a>
                  <a class="nav-link top-link " href="#ourworld" title='OUR WORLD'>OUR WORLD</a>
                  <a class="nav-link top-link " href="#wheretosip" title='WHERE TO SIP'>WHERE TO SIP</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
REST OF THE PAGE
```

Comment: Possibly related https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/36431

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: @CarolSkelly Bootstrap 5. I Also realized data-offset isn't used for the actual offset of the scrolling but for highlighting the section of the navbar. 
I managed to build a jquery function that covers what i needed. Thanks anyway.